# Git merge conflict: different branch edits different lines

Tags: git

I am testing out some circumstances on `git merge`
I created a sample.txt, see succeeding actions below

add then commit to master branch
sample.txt contains

```
aaa  
bbb
```

create and checkout to branch1 and edits sample.txt---add then commit
**branch1** sample.txt

```
aaa  
bbc
```

checks out to master and edits sample.txt---add then commit
**master** sample.txt

```
aad  
bbb
```

runs `git merge branch1` i receive the following notification

```
Auto-merging sample  
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in sample  
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

sample.txt contains

```
<<<<<<< HEAD  
aad  
bbb  
=======  
aaa  
bbc  
>>>>>>>> branch1
```

master made an edit on line 1
branch1 made an edit on line 2
i would understand the merge conflict if i edit line 1 on master and branch1

what is the merge conflict in this scenario?
how to have the output of sample.txt below?

```
aad  
bbc
```

Comment: Please don't add language tags for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge conflict is that in `HEAD` you have

```
aad
bbb
```

whereas in `Branch1` you have

```
aaa
bbc
```

to resolve this conflict pick if you want `aad` or `aaa` and pick between `bbb` and `bbc`. If you want `aad` and `bbc` for example replace:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD  
aad  
bbb  
=======  
aaa  
bbc  
>>>>>>>> branch1
```

with

```
aad
bbc
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, this setting in your git config will come in handy when handling merge conflicts ; this helps to know the common base for the files being merged.

**git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3**

Source:
[14 ways to resolve merge conflicts](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/12/tips-tools-to-solve-git-conflicts/)